# Triggering external content on left side of the Page in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just started using Bootstrap and I found this interesting piece of code in their docs

```
    <div class="pos-f-t">
  <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="bg-inverse p-4">
      <h4 class="text-white">Collapsed content</h4>
      <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I have two question here.

what is `pos-f-t` I can't find any docs relating to that and how can I make the content in the scroll to come on other sides of the page like left/right.
I hope I am making some sense.

Comment: The .pos-f-t class can be used to easily position elements at the top of the viewport. And the second part of your question... I don't get it.

Comment: see now when I click the button the content of the div slide from the top of the page. What I want is that if I click the button the div content should come from left side. @Wizzard Hope you understand.

Comment: Thats a very different effect. Atm the div slided in, is animated by height. You would have to do a custom animation by width... Not a Bootstrap default thing.